# How to stop page reloading on WFFM form when validation/save action failed?

Tags: wffm, mvc-forms

I'm using Sitecore 8.2 update 5 with the corresponding WFFM version. When WFFM form fails validation/custom submit action failed the application is redirecting the user to a page with the form only, I'd like to make it ajax and keep the user on the initial page.

I checked "Is Ajax Mvc Form" on the form which was supposed to do the job but it still redirects me to something like http://website/form/Index?wffm.FormItemId=6cf4975d-b1... Am I missing something or it's a bug?

Comment: Seem like you are missing the required Javascript files (which should be added by the MVC Form component automatically in that version of WFFM) or you have a Javascript conflict causing the code to fail. Check your dev console for any errors.